# ¿Cómo obtener promedio de datos por día en Mongodb?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb

Quiero saber si hay una manera de obtener el promedio de datos por día usando una agregación. Aquí hay una muestra de mis datos:

```
[{"eApa":70519217,"pReacTotal":-111920,"pAparTotal":169404,"eCap":44641702,"eInd":478186,"vL1":127.646484375,"eActImp":41766944,"time":1564763657341},{"eApa":70520927,"pReacTotal":-123544,"pAparTotal":159832,"eCap":44642873,"eInd":478186,"vL1":127.9453125,"eActImp":41768133,"time":1564763694724},{"eApa":70522183,"pReacTotal":-139188,"pAparTotal":176512,"eCap":44643864,"eInd":478186,"vL1":127.771484375,"eActImp":41768890,"time":1564763716707},{"eApa":70522513,"pReacTotal":-155828,"pAparTotal":196372,"eCap":44644128,"eInd":478186,"vL1":127.865234375,"eActImp":41769086,"time":1564763722905},{"eApa":70524589,"pReacTotal":-165072,"pAparTotal":226156,"eCap":44645715,"eInd":478186,"vL1":127.486328125,"eActImp":41770404,"time":1564763760126},{"eApa":70526081,"pReacTotal":-168376,"pAparTotal":249252,"eCap":44646779,"eInd":478186,"vL1":127.142578125,"eActImp":41771487,"time":1564763782323}]
```

Como puede ver, el campo de tiempo es de tipo largo, pero no sé cómo obtener el promedio de los datos que corresponde a un día. Quiero decir, los datos en el ejemplo son para el 2 de agosto, hay más datos que son para el 3 de agosto y hasta la fecha actual. Y quiero obtener el promedio solo para cada día para los otros campos, por ejemplo, comenzó el 2 de agosto a las 00:00:00 hasta las 23:59:59.

Aquí está el código en Nodejs que trae los datos:

```
TestC.aggregate([
            {
                '$match': {
                    'time': {
                        '$gte': new Date(Date.now() - (/* 86400 */ 2332800 * 1000))
                    }
                }
            }, {
                '$project': {
                    '_id': 0,
                    'pAparTotal': 1,
                    'pReacTotal': 1,
                    'eApa': 1,
                    'eInd': 1,
                    'eCap': 1,
                    'eActImp': 1,
                    'time': {
                        '$toLong': '$time'
                    }
                }
            }, {
                '$sort': {
                    'time': 1
                }
            }
        ]).exec((ex, data) => {
            if (ex) return res.status(500).send({ message: "Error tryng to get the data" });

            if (!data) return res.status(400).send({ message: No data." });

            if (data) return res.status(200).send(data)
        });
```

Gracias!

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a [es.so]. Por lo que puedo entender de tu pregunta, deseas obtener los promedios de cada campo por fecha. Veo que en tu proceso de agregación estás pasando el valor: ___`new Date(Date.now() - (/* 86400 */ 2332800 * 1000)`___ . Imagino que el mismo indica algún punto en el tiempo en particular, pero creo que podrías lograrlo de otra manera (sin hacer un *hardcode*). Aparte de la consulta que devuelve tus datos, ¿has intentado algo por tu cuenta? Si es así, deberías subir el código de lo que hayas intentado. Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) y [$avg](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/avg/#grp._S_avg) creo que podrías sacar lo que buscas. Lo que no me queda claro es qué campos necesitas sacar una media. Sin embargo te dejo un ejemplo:

```
[
     {
       $group:
         {
           _id : { $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$time" } },
           avgAmount: { $avg: { $multiply: [ "$price", "$quantity" ] } },
           avgQuantity: { $avg: "$quantity" }
         }
     }
]
```

Espero que te sirva de ayuda.